# Hover function not working on appended div content after append function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add content with append function. But hover function not working on new div content after append. Can I get help about this?

jsfiddle code here : https://jsfiddle.net/xpwrv8mo/

JS CODE:

```
$('#add').click(function(){   
$('.temp-wrapper').append('<div class="temp"><div class="icon-del"></div><div>new content</div></div>');
});

$(".temp").hover(function(){
$(this).find(".icon-del").show();
},function(){ $(this).find(".icon-del").hide(); });

$(".icon-del").click(function(event) {
if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;
$(this).parent().remove();
return true;
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
    <div class="temp-wrapper">
    <div class="temp"><div class="icon-del"></div><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="temp"><div class="icon-del"></div><div>B</div></div>
    <div class="temp"><div class="icon-del"></div><div>C</div></div>
    </div>
<p style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" class="button" id="add" value="ADD" /></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic event triggers, if you use .click() they are only attached to elements that exist at that time. If you use the following code any click within an element with class `.temp-wrapper` is checked against the given selectors before running the associated function.

```
$(".temp-wrapper").on("mouseenter", ".temp", function(){ ...  });

$(".temp-wrapper").on("mouseleave", ".temp",function(){ ... });

$(".temp-wrapper").on("click", ".icon-del", function(event) { ... });
```

---

## Demo

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('.temp-wrapper').append('<div class="temp"><div class="icon-del"></div><div>new content</div></div>');
});

$(".temp-wrapper").on("mouseenter", ".temp", function() {
  $(this).find(".icon-del").show();
});

$(".temp-wrapper").on("mouseleave", ".temp", function() {
  $(this).find(".icon-del").hide();
});

$(".temp-wrapper").on("click", ".icon-del", function(event) {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;
  $(this).parent().remove();
  return true;
});
```

```css
.icon-del {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="temp-wrapper">
  <div class="temp">
    <div class="icon-del"></div>
    <div>A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="temp">
    <div class="icon-del"></div>
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="temp">
    <div class="icon-del"></div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" class="button" id="add" value="ADD" /></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, now working perfectly. And thank you again for helpful info.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Comment: Better and more efficient to listen on `$('.temp-wrapper')` rather than `$(document)` in this case.

Comment: Definitely - I've updated my answer, thanks for your input.